# How continue normal line in dashed line chart (same line) in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want my normal line to continue in dashed line in char. I have chart from above:
[image]

Green line i want to continue on 2017/18 to be green and dashed but continue from the same line.

My code for this is that:

```
Dim OpenApu As New Series
            Dim ClosedApu As New Series
            Dim TargetWorkingAverage As New Series

            OpenApu.Name = "Sum of APU units open"
            ClosedApu.Name = "Sum of APU units closed"
            TargetWorkingAverage.Name = "Target Working Average"

            OpenApu.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            ClosedApu.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            TargetWorkingAverage.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

            OpenApu.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            OpenApu.BorderWidth = 3

            ClosedApu.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
            ClosedApu.BorderWidth = 3

            TargetWorkingAverage.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black
            TargetWorkingAverage.BorderWidth = 3
            TargetWorkingAverage.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash
            TargetWorkingAverage.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine
' this i put my values from chart
ClosedApu.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.Year & "/" & i + 1, TotalCost2)
```

What i try, at final line to change style of line in dashed but change style for all line.

```
    OpenApu.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
    OpenApu.BorderWidth = 3
    OpenApu.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash
    OpenApu.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine

    ClosedApu.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green
    ClosedApu.BorderWidth = 3
    ClosedApu.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash
    ClosedApu.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine

    OpenApu.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.Year & "/" & i + 1, 5000)
    ClosedApu.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.Year & "/" & i + 1, 6000)
```

When  try to change style in dahsed doesn't work, all my line is dashed but i want to continue un dahsed not all my line to be dashed.

Comment: which control are you using? it's not specified...